# AppCompat PopUp menu RuntimeException

Tags: android, popupmenu

I am using following class to create iconized popup menu:

```
public class IconizedMenu implements MenuBuilder.Callback, MenuPresenter.Callback {
    private Context mContext;
    private MenuBuilder mMenu;
    private View mAnchor;
    private MenuPopupHelper mPopup;
    private OnMenuItemClickListener mMenuItemClickListener;
    private OnDismissListener mDismissListener;

    /**
     * Callback interface used to notify the application that the menu has closed.
     */
    public interface OnDismissListener {
        /**
         * Called when the associated menu has been dismissed.
         *
         * @param menu The PopupMenu that was dismissed.
         */
        public void onDismiss(IconizedMenu menu);
    }

    /**
     * Construct a new PopupMenu.
     *
     * @param context Context for the PopupMenu.
     * @param anchor Anchor view for this popup. The popup will appear below the anchor if there
     * is room, or above it if there is not.
     */
    public IconizedMenu(Context context, View anchor) {
        mContext = context;
        mMenu = new MenuBuilder(context);
        mMenu.setCallback(this);
        mAnchor = anchor;
        mPopup = new MenuPopupHelper(context, mMenu, anchor);
        mPopup.setCallback(this);
        mPopup.setForceShowIcon(true);
    }

    /**
     * @return the {@link android.view.Menu} associated with this popup. Populate the returned Menu with
     * items before calling {@link #show()}.
     *
     * @see #show()
     * @see #getMenuInflater()
     */
    public Menu getMenu() {
        return mMenu;
    }

    /**
     * @return a {@link android.view.MenuInflater} that can be used to inflate menu items from XML into the
     * menu returned by {@link #getMenu()}.
     *
     * @see #getMenu()
     */
    public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
        return new SupportMenuInflater(mContext);
    }

    /**
     * Inflate a menu resource into this PopupMenu. This is equivalent to calling
     * popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(menuRes, popupMenu.getMenu()).
     * @param menuRes Menu resource to inflate
     */
    public void inflate(int menuRes) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(menuRes, mMenu);
    }

    /**
     * Show the menu popup anchored to the view specified during construction.
     * @see #dismiss()
     */
    public void show() {
        mPopup.show();
    }

    /**
     * Dismiss the menu popup.
     * @see #show()
     */
    public void dismiss() {
        mPopup.dismiss();
    }

    /**
     * Set a listener that will be notified when the user selects an item from the menu.
     *
     * @param listener Listener to notify
     */
    public void setOnMenuItemClickListener(OnMenuItemClickListener listener) {
        mMenuItemClickListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Set a listener that will be notified when this menu is dismissed.
     *
     * @param listener Listener to notify
     */
    public void setOnDismissListener(OnDismissListener listener) {
        mDismissListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * @hide
     */
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder menu, MenuItem item) {
        if (mMenuItemClickListener != null) {
            return mMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick(item);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @hide
     */
    public void onCloseMenu(MenuBuilder menu, boolean allMenusAreClosing) {
        if (mDismissListener != null) {
            mDismissListener.onDismiss(this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @hide
     */
    public boolean onOpenSubMenu(MenuBuilder subMenu) {
        if (subMenu == null) return false;

        if (!subMenu.hasVisibleItems()) {
            return true;
        }

// Current menu will be dismissed by the normal helper, submenu will be shown in its place.
        new MenuPopupHelper(mContext, subMenu, mAnchor).show();
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @hide
     */
    public void onCloseSubMenu(SubMenuBuilder menu) {
    }

    /**
     * @hide
     */
    public void onMenuModeChange(MenuBuilder menu) {
    }

    /**
     * Interface responsible for receiving menu item click events if the items themselves
     * do not have individual item click listeners.
     */
    public interface OnMenuItemClickListener {
        /**
         * This method will be invoked when a menu item is clicked if the item itself did
         * not already handle the event.
         *
         * @param item {@link MenuItem} that was clicked
         * @return <code>true</code> if the event was handled, <code>false</code> otherwise.
         */
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item);
    }

}
```

However if I try to run it on lolipop it causes error. It works fine on devices with API level < 21. Here is the logcat:

```
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824): Process: hzs.sk.hzs, PID: 3824
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     ... 10 more
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:603)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:6423)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:6591)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:735)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:679)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:62)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper$MenuAdapter.getView(MenuPopupHelper.java:370)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.measureContentWidth(MenuPopupHelper.java:219)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:153)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.show(MenuPopupHelper.java:125)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at hzs.sk.hzs.IconizedMenu.show(IconizedMenu.java:88)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at hzs.sk.hzs.MainActivity.showMenu(MainActivity.java:294)
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     ... 13 more
```

activity which uses this extends Activity, not ActionBarActivity. Any ideas why is it generating an error?

Thanks in forward

**EDIT:** I have tried using default appCompat PopUp menu (so its without icons) and it is throwing same error. Any ideas?

Comment: I am getting same error when using default AppCompat v7 popup menu

Comment: It might be helpful for some you: just use the right "context" when initializing PopUpMenu, in my case, I was using "applicationContext", then changed it to fragment's context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case [MenuPopupHelper.MenuAdapter#getView()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/support/v7/internal/view/menu/MenuPopupHelper.java#MenuPopupHelper.MenuAdapter.getView%28int%2Candroid.view.View%2Candroid.view.ViewGroup%29) try to inflate [ITEM_LAYOUT = R.layout.abc_popup_menu_item_layout](https://cells-source.cs.columbia.edu/plugins/gitiles/platform/frameworks/support/+/ee7c9fb199e9b9af8d40a1f9e27d85465acf8301/v7/appcompat/res/layout/abc_popup_menu_item_layout.xml) and during this process [android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ListMenuItemView](https://cells-source.cs.columbia.edu/plugins/gitiles/platform/frameworks/support/+/ee7c9fb199e9b9af8d40a1f9e27d85465acf8301/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/view/menu/ListMenuItemView.java) created and require 
[R.styleable.MenuView](https://cells-source.cs.columbia.edu/plugins/gitiles/platform/frameworks/support/+/ee7c9fb199e9b9af8d40a1f9e27d85465acf8301/v7/appcompat/res/values/attrs.xml) (look inside to find - **declare-styleable name="MenuView"**) where attribute at index 6 is **attr name="android:itemIconDisabledAlpha"** this mean that no this attribute defined in application theme. Required attribute defined in `<style name="Theme">` for any platform as `<item name="disabledAlpha">0.5</item>` this is [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/2ef2d49aa3c19e99e2a753dac2dfb51fc87b5328/core/res/res/values/themes.xml).

To use default value just extend application theme by one of the themes that extends `<style name="Theme">`.

I recommend following solution:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

or any other Theme.AppCompat with NoActionBar
if you want to use [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) for older than v21 platforms with all new features available as replacement of ActionBar component.

But actually feel free to use other themes like Holo or Material if it's really required.

Good luck!

And feel free to ask.

Answer (score 30):

If you are using Appcompat and lollipop try adding new style

```
<style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#0F213F</item>
    <item name="android:disabledAlpha">0.5</item>
</style>
```

and create the popup menu

```
Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.MyPopupMenu);
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, view);
```

Comment: Thanks, really helped me ! :)

Comment: Helped me too! Thanks you dude, you are awesome and you save my day!

Comment: This is the correct solution for customizing a popup dialog that is not attached necessarily to the toolbar. Worked for me, needed a popup menu attached to an overflow button from a recycler view item.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem of a missing or changed style attribute as indicated by

`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6
02-15 06:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3824):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:603)`

Internally android looks up style attributes with `?attr/` in the local theme context.
Try to debug the code line in which that happens to find out which style is missing.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea on how to do this. My style.xml has nothing on line 6. Can you point me in right direction? I have tried putting debug point on line 88 of iconized menu and I caught an exception but I dont know what is meant by idnex 6

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Only problem was that I had the following declaration in my values-v21/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
</style>
```

So I changed it to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

and it is working great now.