# Exception - failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue

Tags: android

I'm seeing the following exception:

```
04-06 13:35:58.498  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x46 "res/color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark.xml" a=2 r=0x7f0e00e5}
04-06 13:35:58.498  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
04-06 13:35:58.498  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:    at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
04-06 13:35:58.498  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
04-06 13:35:58.498  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper$MenuAdapter.getView(MenuPopupHelper.java:374)
04-06 13:35:58.498  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.measureContentWidth(MenuPopupHelper.java:223)
04-06 13:35:58.498  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:157)
04-06 13:35:58.498  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter$OpenOverflowRunnable.run(ActionMenuPresenter.java:781)
04-06 13:35:58.498  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-06 13:35:58.498  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-06 13:35:58.498  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
04-06 13:35:58.498  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
04-06 13:35:58.498  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-06 13:35:58.498  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
04-06 13:35:58.498  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-06 13:35:58.498  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x46 "res/color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark.xml" a=2 r=0x7f0e00e5}
04-06 13:35:58.498  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:705)
04-06 13:35:58.498  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:6890)
04-06 13:35:58.498  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:7071)
04-06 13:35:58.498  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:446)
04-06 13:35:58.498  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:386)
04-06 13:35:58.498  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:385)
04-06 13:35:58.498  4219  4219 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:502)
```

This has happened twice now when I clicked the menu button in my Toolbar. Unfortunately, it seems to be quite unpredictable and happened twice out of a lot of attempts. My menu looks like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <item android:id="@+id/menu_action_show_project_startup"
    android:title="@string/menu_action_project_intro"
    android:orderInCategory="300"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

  <item android:id="@+id/menu_action_report_issue"
      android:title="@string/menu_action_report_issue"
      android:orderInCategory="300"
      app:showAsAction="never"/>

  <item android:id="@+id/menu_action_toggle_mobile_data"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:checked="true"
    android:title="@string/menu_action_toggle_mobile_data"
    android:orderInCategory="500"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

  <item android:id="@+id/menu_action_logout"
    android:title="@string/menu_action_logout"
    android:orderInCategory="600"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

I had a look at a similar question - [Android XML: RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595187/android-xml-runtimeexception-failed-to-resolve-attribute-at-index-6) - but my problem doesn't seem to originate from the FAB button and I am using AppCompat in my app.

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: Hey, Did you find solution for your problem? If yes, you can answer this question, so that it can help others in case they face the similar issue :)

Comment: look at the for the answer of @Amir Dadgari in the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523517/appcompat-popup-menu-runtimeexception

Answer (score 5):

Based on the above solution from TaoBit, I realized that the issue was with my theme was not acceptable in Marshmallow. So I replaced

```
<style name="Dark.Overlay" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

with this and it all worked. Thanks TaoBit for the hint. You saved 2 days worth of work and a lot of headache. I am loving SO by the day.

```
<style name="MyToolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the bug report from Google, make sure you use the correct theme

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=152141

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and it was caused by having the following line in my dimens.xml file:

```
<dimen name="viewname_padding_top">?actionBarSize</dimen>
```

so I replaced it with:

```
<dimen name="viewname_padding_top">@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material</dimen>
```

Answer (score 1):

I my case, I had in colors.xml

```
<color name="textColorTitle">?themeColorPrimary</color>
```

when I set it to a real value instead of an attribute, it worked.

```
<color name="textColorTitle">@color/colorPrimary</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case there were several files styles.xml (for different API levels):

```
.../res/values-v19/styles.xml
.../res/values-v21/styles.xml
.../res/values-v23/styles.xml
```

When I added my custom attribute to ALL theese files (and all used themes inside theese files) - everything worked.