# Android PopupMenu keeps crashing

Tags: android, popupmenu

So I setup a CardView to open a PopupMenu, but it just keeps crashing, no matter what I have tried.

Here's the XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardview_gender"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/edittext_height"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:onClick="getGender"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorTransparent"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/edittext_gender"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hint_gender"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And here's the method:

```
public void getGender(View view) {

    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, view);
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.item_girl:
                    editText_gender.setText(string_boy);
                    return true;
                case R.id.item_boy:
                    editText_gender.setText(string_girl);
                    return true;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }
    });
    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.gender_menu);
    popupMenu.show();

}
```

And of course, here's the error log:

> 07-22 16:40:04.299 24031-24031/com.avena.avenafit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                       Process: com.avena.avenafit, PID: 24031
>                                                                       Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.materialos.cm.theme, iconPack:com.launchertheme.kxnt.pop, fontPkg:com.materialos.cm.theme, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.materialos.cm.theme, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.materialos.cm.theme}
>                                                                       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected receiver of type com.avena.avenafit.onboarding.w, but got android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                           at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4453)
>                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
>                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21158)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

I have also tried setting up an onClickListener on the CardView, but it gives me this error:

> 07-22 17:08:14.297 8834-8834/com.avena.avenafit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                     Process: com.avena.avenafit, PID: 8834
>                                                                     Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.materialos.cm.theme, iconPack:com.launchertheme.kxnt.pop, fontPkg:com.materialos.cm.theme, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.materialos.cm.theme, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.materialos.cm.theme}
>                                                                     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x1d/d=0xffffc107 a=3 r=0x7f0d0004}
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.w.getView(Unknown Source)
>                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.v.i(Unknown Source)
>                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.v.f(Unknown Source)
>                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.v.d(Unknown Source)
>                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ea.b(Unknown Source)
>                                                                         at com.avena.avenafit.onboarding.x.onClick(Unknown Source)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
>                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21158)
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x1d/d=0xffffc107 a=3 r=0x7f0d0004}
>                                                                         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:705)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:6890)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.(ViewGroup.java:7071)
>                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.(FrameLayout.java:446)
>                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:386)
>                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:385)
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:502)
>                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.w.getView(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.v.i(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.v.f(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.v.d(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ea.b(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                         at com.avena.avenafit.onboarding.x.onClick(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204) 
>                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21158) 
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Has anyone struggled with this before?

Comment: Your problem has to do with the theme of your app/the popup.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: The first part of the error is talking about themes and an IllegalArgumentException... `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected receiver of type com.avena.avenafit.onboarding.w, but got android.view.ContextThemeWrapper`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution:

Just don't use the onClick attribute in XML, just declare a regular onClickListener for your cardView and add it via setOnClickListener.

Edit: About the other error, this might be helpful: [AppCompat PopUp menu RuntimeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523517/appcompat-popup-menu-runtimeexception)
The error indicates that there might be some style attribute missing.

Comment: As you can read at the end of my original question, I already tried that. It gives a different error. I have added it to my post up here.

Comment: Maybe this one helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523517/appcompat-popup-menu-runtimeexception ? Seems to be quite similar to your errors. "Failed to resolve attribute at index 6" indicates that there's some attribute missing.

Comment: @S.Martell did you remove this row "android:onClick="getGender"" when you set up a listener via setOnClickListener?

Comment: @AlexeyRogovoy I did.

Comment: @S.Martell Could you provide a full layout xml file which throws InflateException?