# RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6

Tags: android, menu

I have a button that is in a **fragment**. When I click the button, It should show a **popup menu**. But It doens't.

These are my error messages :

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.ias.caniasandroid, PID: 22823
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6
>                         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:603)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:6473)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.(ViewGroup.java:6641)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.(FrameLayout.java:741)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:685)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:62)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper$MenuAdapter.getView(MenuPopupHelper.java:374)
>                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.measureContentWidth(MenuPopupHelper.java:223)
>                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:157)
>                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.show(MenuPopupHelper.java:129)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.show(PopupMenu.java:216)

My menu XML file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/login_menu_new_item"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/new_ias"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/login_menu_edit_item"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/edit"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/login_menu_delete_item"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/delete"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
</menu>
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Maybe You should try `android.widget.PopupMenu` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu`. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27826670/404395).

Comment: @marioosh hmm let me check this. Aww yes, Thank you it works.

Comment: look at the for the answer of @Amir Dadgari in the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523517/appcompat-popup-menu-runtimeexception

Answer (score -1):

It might be for too many style.css file.

Add below in build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```